# How process knows when to stop listening for receive?

Tags: c++, mpi, boost-mpl

Consider a mesh whose bins are decomposed among processes. The numbers in the image are the ranks of processes.

At each time step, some of the points displace so that it is needed to send them to new destinations. This point-sending is done by all processes having displaced points. In the image only the points of lower-left corner bin are shown as an example.

I don't know how long should a process keep listening for receive messages? The problem is that a receiver does not even know whether a message would arrive or not because no point might pass to its region.

Also note that, the source and destination of a point might be the same as for blue point.

[image]

Edit: Below is an incomplete code to express the problem.

```
void transfer_points()
{
    world.isend(dest, ...);
    while (true)
    {
        mpi::status msg = world.iprobe(any_source, any_tag);
        if (msg.count() != 0)
        {
            world.irecv(any_source, ...);
        }

        // but how long keep probing?
        if (???) {break;}            
    }
}
```

Comment: You basically have to send a special stop message.

Comment: What about first using `MPI_Alltoall()` to tell how many messages to expect from each process?

Comment: I would suggest always sending a message to all neighbours, even if there are no points to transfer, which means that that every receive will always complete. To indicate that this is a null message you could use a special tag, or alternatively use MPI_Get_count to find out the length of the incoming message.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with one-sided MPI or RMA (Remote Memory Access) via MPI_Win_* operations? The way I understand your problem, it should be solvable neatly with it:

- Ranks that send some points just put it into the other rank's memory (window).
- Barrier
- Receivers have directly went to the barrier, and are now in possession of the data

Here is an example of a ring send with RMA (In c++ syntax!). In your situation it should only need some minor modification, i. e. only call `MPI_Put` if necessary and some math about the offsets to write into the buffer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  MPI::Init(argc,argv);    
  int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
  int comm_size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();    
  int neighbor_left = rank - 1;
  int neighbor_right = rank + 1; 

  //Left and right most are neighbors.
  if(neighbor_right >= comm_size) { neighbor_right = 0;}
  if(neighbor_left < 0) {neighbor_left = comm_size - 1;}

  int postbox[2];
  MPI::Win window = MPI::Win::Create(postbox,2,sizeof(int),MPI_INFO_NULL,MPI::COMM_WORLD);

  window.Fence(0);     
  // Put my rank in the second entry of my left neighbor (I'm his right neighbor)
  window.Put(&rank,1,MPI_INT,neighbor_left,1,1,MPI_INT);
  window.Fence(0);    
  // Put my rank in the first entry of my right neighbor (I'm his left neighbor)
  window.Put(&rank,1,MPI_INT,neighbor_right,0,1,MPI_INT);
  window.Fence(0);

  std::cout << "I'm rank = " << rank << " my Neighbors (l-r) are " << postbox[0] << " " << postbox[1] << std::endl;

  MPI::Finalize();  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like RMA could solve the problem. I will report back when I am done with this. Thx.